# What is this two-columned selection dialog called?

Tags: gui-design, terminology, dialog

What is the name, if there is one, for the following dialog type?

[image: Dialog for choosing stuff from two columns]

Are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is commonly referred to as a **[list builder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_builder)**.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative for such a dialog, especially when the number of options isn't that big, would be just a list of items with checkboxes:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqIZVc.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>